# Is there a way to measure how technologically and economically independent a country is?

Tags: economy, technology, science

Is there a way to measure how technologically and economically independent a country is?

With all this talk of derisking and banning technologies to other countries, I was wondering if there was a way to measure how dependent a country is technologically and economically if all countries were to cut off technology, economy and science like the world did against North Korea. I am wondering how independent Europe, the United States and China are to the rest of the world.

Comment: Is the word "measure" used in a technical sense of *quantifying* dependency, or just in the general sense of being able to judge? For example, China maintains as much as possible a complete and self-sufficient economy, in order to de-tooth US sanction threats, and it does it on purpose, so it can certainly judge it's own dependency. But there's no quantification.

Comment: quantifying, if there's not any, you can choose to answer the question in any way you want.

Comment: "all countries were to cut off technology, economy and science like the world did against North Korea." All countries did no such thing. Some countries did and some countries didn't.

Comment: There is also [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) where a different but similar question could be asked, something like "Have *metrics been proposed as a way to compare* their relative technological and economical independence?"

Comment: A problem I foresee with any such metric is that it will fail to tell the whole political story. Sure if Taiwan shut its doors to the US the US would be in trouble, so in that sense the US seems more technologically dependent than, say, Taiwan. Yet if the US faced a crisis of access to ICs, there would be economic and political effects felt around the world, not least by Taiwan in particular. Who is really dependent on whom in that situation? It's not clear and I think doing that kind of analysis misses the broader point: we're all bound up in one global economy.

Comment: Also, "Europe" is not a country

Answer (score 18):

**No, or at least not easily.**

Dependency could be dependency on a source of imports, dependency on a market for exports, dependency on transshipment, dependency on foreign investment or experts, or more. Each of these has to be examined, by sector, and alternatives have to be evaluated.

For instance, a couple of years ago Germany got over 80% of cocoa imports directly or indirectly from Ivory Coast. It would be extremely difficult to find a substitute supplier. But then, one can actually live without chocolate.

Germany used to get much sunflower oil from Ukraine. After the Russian invasion in 2022, there were severe sunflower oil shortages. Customers switched to rapeseed oil and *refined* olive oil, which caused shortages in those fields. There was never any shortage in the more expensive grades like *virgin* or *extra virgin*. Germany as a whole did not have a vegetable oil shortage, while poorer segments of the population did.

Germany is also importing and exporting a significant percentage by weight/volume through the Dutch port of Rotterdam. German ports could not possibly take the traffic if that was somehow blocked. But then you listed "Europe" as a country in your question. Germany and the Netherlands are both in the EU.

Any attempt to get all this into a *single* assessment or ranking has to make assumptions about the willingness of the population to substitute, the state of the world markets, etc.

Comment: Then again, "making [hopefully empirics based] assumptions" is what developers of benchmarks and indices do all the time. I suspect a deeper key challenge behind such a "dependency index" is that it's hard to put a number on technological dependence in the first place. How much does it actually cost a country to lose access to semiconductor foundries?

Comment: This could be witnessed last year when Russia was cut off of Swift - there was a lot of confident posturing from both sides, but my strong impression was that nobody really knew what the impact of that measure on Russia would be (and even now it's hard to say how big the impact *was*). It's hard to construct a useful index when you don't even really know the value of the base metrics that should go into the index.

Comment: @xLeitix, the problem with an index is that it suggested a one-dimensional scale and a clear ranking on it. For dependency, one should think in scenarios. What does it mean if the ROC cannot sell any more? What does it mean if the PRC refuses to sell? Is there a crisis in other sectors as well? Did some event strengthen domestic morale, or did another event weaken it? Too many variables for *one* index.

Comment: *one can actually live without chocolate* Citation needed.

Comment: One minor correction: there is no such thing as a *shortage* in economics. You can have a situation where a good is temporarily sold out because the sellers haven't adjusted their prices quickly enough but over time all shortages are corrected for via pricing mechanisms. I.e. the GPU shortage in 2020 only happened because Nvidia refused to jack up the prices by 5-10x to ensure that they never sell out.

Comment: @JonathanReez, here you and I have a fundamental disagreement. I believe that all humans *should* have a balanced diet, and if market forces makes part of that unavailable, that *is* a shortage. GPUs are less vital for human life. (I realize that mankind is far from reaching this ideal, and I'm not rushing out to donate *all* my money to those without sufficient food, but I believe that it is an ideal mankind should try to reach.)

Comment: Yes you definitely need *some* form of protein, fats and carbs. But as long as *some* form is available at a reasonable price, there is no "shortage". This includes meat for example, as evidenced by 100 million vegetarians in India.

Comment: @JonathanReez, and in this case, the fats they used to buy were no longer in the supermarkets, and for some parts of the population there was no *reasonably* priced alternative. For other parts of the population, the alternatives were affordable. Shortages. And in some other parts of the world, the increasing grain costs were much more dramatic.

Comment: There’s no “shortage” if a reasonable alternative is still available. Yes if even bread is no longer available we could talk about shortages but chocolate or sunflower oil? Not a shortage.

Comment: @JonathanReez, the French Queen is often misquoted as having said "let them eat cake." Same here, yet France had a severe bread shortage at the time.

Comment: Again - if even bread is not available we can talk about a “shortage”. But rapeseed oil or chocolate don’t have shortages, they either have companies that misprinted their goods or consumers that switch to other products because the price has increased. Economics does not have a “shortage” concept because it’s absurd.

Answer (score 6):

Dependency between countries is a tricky thing to quantify, or even to fully characterise.

One complication is that dependency is not just about the current facts of the matter, but about how the facts could be changed by will or by accident.

For example, there may be some banana republic controlling a territory with rare minerals, and therefore there is dependency on that country currently.

But if you are US or China, or many other large and militarily significant countries, you could in the final resort blow the regime to kingdom come and absorb their territory, so the dependency only really exists at will of the potential conqueror.

So-called adaptive preferences are another confounding factor. The vast majority of things which you currently depend on, can be done without or substituted - either immediately, or after a short transition time.

Whether you need something might also depend on what your military opponents have access to, not on your own needs as analysed independently. Again, these opponents may be actual under the current circumstances, or would-be opponents under some future alteration of circumstances.

The mental resources necessary for this kind of analysis exceeds any one human mind and would strain a collective of minds to perform even partially, and the results would not usefully reduce to a simple percentage of dependency, or other arithmetical measure on a number line.

Any attempt to reduce each country to a simple number would just produce muddy, middling numbers on an artificial scale, in which all countries are somewhat dependent but also have large latitudes for adaptation or reorganisation if that dependency is in any way pressed, with the result that the number means nothing (and probably any variation between countries just being an artefact of how the numerical analysis was conceived, rather than measuring an important difference in the underlying reality).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that all large modern countries are interdependent with each other.

For many items, the supply chains are quite intermingled. With time and money, the chains could disentangled.

This will not happen quickly. Think weeks to months for simple stuff and years to decades for complex stuff.

Replacement becomes even harder with certain roadblocks. Not every country has all material required for modern items (lithium, oil, uranium, etc.). Some equipment (such as extreme ultraviolet [EUV] lithography machines) are only made by one company. Recreating those may take long time, as EUV is the result of decades of semiconductor research.

Assuming you have all the parts and knowledge, it can take 5-8 years to build the infrastructure for 10nm class chip plant from scratch. Then 2-3 years for the plant. Without those, you will see why there are are not more competitors to TMSC and Intel.

The cost of not being interdependent is quite high. Recreating/rebuilding all imports without any money from exports requires a large and rich country. All of them are interdependent. As a very crude proxy, you could look at import/export numbers. Even then, do you look at percentages or absolute dollars?